# Memory efficient way of using clip_roi for bigger areas

Tags: r, lidr

I am trying to clip LAS files from a `LAScatalog` object based on a polygon boundary (`sf` object). However, since the area of interest is too big, the `clip_roi` function might eventually like mid way during processing, use up 64 gigs of RAM and return a memory error.

What's an efficient of clipping a large ROI from a `LAScatalog` list object? Maybe, I can clip the LAS tiles as smaller chunks and save them as separate LAS files for the ROI.

Code:

```
# Clip ROI 
ROI_LiDAR = clip_roi(LAS_List, sf_object)
```

sf_object:

```
structure(list(Shape_Leng = 49370.2774559, Shape_Area = 23979961.3995, 
    geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(292295.8257, 
    279520.772, 279013.1797, 270203.7357, 270204.1031, 270202.1163, 
    270206.3197, 279433.9815, 279439.6905, 279445.4628, 279451.29, 
    279457.1626, 279463.072, 279469.0088, 279474.9641, 279480.9285, 
    279573.663, 279615.6045, 281159.7593, 281176.7118, 281257.6747, 
    281261.6275, 281754.5418, 281756.1734, 281757.786, 281759.3611, 
    281760.8806, 281762.4543, 281764.1929, 281766.0008, 281767.8507, 
    281769.7148, 281771.5649, 281796.1833, 281796.4446, 281796.7065, 
    281796.9693, 281797.2325, 281797.4964, 281797.7606, 281797.7887, 
    281864.6869, 281865.7456, 281866.8052, 281867.8658, 281868.9267, 
    281869.3525, 282167.0232, 282872.2444, 282872.3121, 283034.6768, 
    283085.9286, 283161.9034, 283219.3769, 283347.1938, 283675.7239, 
    284008.1191, 284463.9644, 284493.7211, 285089.2929, 285515.6163, 
    285772.5639, 286334.3252, 286730.4062, 286766.7001, 286971.4134, 
    287034.1505, 287037.7259, 287041.3151, 287044.9056, 287048.4847, 
    287067.223, 287068.2783, 287069.3355, 287070.3941, 287071.4538, 
    287072.5144, 287073.5753, 287074.04, 287303.4166, 287628.9974, 
    287631.65, 287634.3026, 287636.9546, 287637.293, 287778.0741, 
    287837.4779, 288084.0667, 288183.0984, 288647.0643, 288648.1287, 
    288935.5226, 289049.7154, 289404.3092, 289486.1413, 289577.7837, 
    289578.3143, 289578.8447, 289579.3746, 289579.9042, 289580.4332, 
    289580.9613, 289581.4884, 289582.0143, 289582.2623, 289648.2895, 
    289650.6103, 289652.9437, 289655.2763, 289657.5939, 289659.8831, 
    289695.7437, 289697.9593, 289700.202, 289702.4593, 289704.7188, 
    289829.1743, 289832.3497, 289835.5209, 289838.6867, 289841.8462, 
    289844.9984, 289848.1426, 289851.2773, 289854.4021, 289857.5158, 
    289860.6174, 289863.7061, 289866.7807, 289869.8406, 289872.8847, 
    289875.9121, 289878.9218, 289881.9129, 289884.8846, 289887.836, 
    289890.7662, 289893.674, 289896.5588, 289899.4197, 289902.256, 
    289905.0665, 289907.8505, 289910.607, 289913.3354, 289916.0348, 
    289918.7042, 289921.343, 289923.9505, 289926.5256, 289929.0676, 
    289931.5757, 289934.0494, 289936.4876, 289938.8899, 289941.2552, 
    289943.5831, 289945.8726, 289948.1233, 289950.3343, 289952.505, 
    289954.6347, 289956.7227, 289958.7686, 289960.7715, 289962.7311, 
    289964.6464, 289966.5173, 289968.3428, 289970.1225, 289971.8558, 
    289973.5424, 289975.1816, 289976.7728, 289978.3156, 289979.8098, 
    289981.2546, 289982.6497, 289983.9946, 289985.2889, 289986.5324, 
    289987.7245, 289988.8649, 289988.9377, 289990.9199, 289992.5474, 
    289994.0961, 289995.5659, 289996.9561, 289998.2663, 289999.4962, 
    290000.6455, 290001.7136, 290002.7005, 290003.6056, 290004.4287, 
    290005.1696, 290005.8281, 290006.404, 290006.8969, 290007.3071, 
    290007.634, 290007.8779, 290008.0383, 290008.1156, 290008.1094, 
    290008.02, 290007.8472, 290007.5912, 290007.252, 290006.8298, 
    290006.3246, 290005.7366, 290005.0659, 290004.313, 290003.4778, 
    290002.5606, 290001.562, 290000.4818, 289999.3207, 289998.0789, 
    289996.7569, 289995.355, 289993.8737, 289992.3133, 289990.6743, 
    289988.9575, 289987.1631, 289985.2917, 289983.344, 289981.3206, 
    289979.2218, 289977.0485, 289975.5406, 289927.6168, 289926.4735, 
    289925.539, 289924.8207, 289924.3237, 289924.0517, 289924.007, 
    289924.1897, 289924.5983, 289925.2302, 289943.9909, 289944.1207, 
    289944.2823, 289944.4526, 289944.6317, 289944.8195, 289945.0158, 
    289945.2208, 289945.4342, 289945.6561, 289945.8865, 289946.125, 
    289946.3719, 289946.6269, 289946.8899, 289947.161, 289947.44, 
    289947.7269, 289948.0214, 289948.3235, 289948.6335, 289948.9507, 
    289949.2753, 289949.6072, 289949.9463, 289950.2924, 289950.6455, 
    289951.0054, 289951.3722, 289951.7456, 289952.1255, 289952.5118, 
    289952.9043, 289953.3031, 289953.7078, 289954.1185, 289954.5351, 
    289954.9572, 289955.385, 289955.8181, 289956.2565, 289956.7001, 
    289957.1486, 289957.6022, 289958.0603, 289958.523, 289958.9903, 
    289959.4619, 289959.9377, 289960.4174, 289960.9011, 289961.3884, 
    289961.8794, 289962.3737, 290079.343, 290081.1711, 290083.0351, 
    290084.928, 290129.4317, 290129.9928, 290131.565, 290133.1412, 
    290134.721, 290136.304, 290137.8896, 290139.4774, 290141.0669, 
    290142.6576, 290144.249, 290145.8407, 290147.4321, 290149.0227, 
    290150.6122, 290152.1999, 290153.7855, 290155.3684, 290156.9482, 
    290158.5242, 290160.0962, 290161.6637, 290163.226, 290164.7828, 
    290166.3336, 290167.8778, 290169.4151, 290170.945, 290172.467, 
    290173.9807, 290175.4855, 290176.981, 290178.4668, 290179.9424, 
    290181.4074, 290182.8613, 290184.3037, 290185.7341, 290187.1521, 
    290188.5573, 290189.9491, 290191.3274, 290192.6915, 290194.041, 
    290195.3758, 290196.6951, 290197.9986, 290199.2861, 290200.5571, 
    290201.8111, 290203.0477, 290204.2667, 290205.4678, 290206.6504, 
    290207.8142, 290208.9589, 290210.0841, 290211.1895, 290212.2748, 
    290213.3395, 290214.3834, 290215.4061, 290216.4076, 290217.3871, 
    290218.3448, 290219.28, 290220.1927, 290221.0824, 290221.949, 
    290222.7921, 290223.6115, 290224.407, 290225.1784, 290225.9253, 
    290226.6476, 290227.3449, 290228.0172, 290228.6643, 290229.2859, 
    290229.8817, 290230.4518, 290230.9959, 290231.5137, 290271.2343, 
    290272.5017, 290273.974, 290275.6465, 290277.5126, 290279.5657, 
    290359.7584, 290361.204, 290362.788, 290364.5013, 290366.3335, 
    290368.2736, 290370.3102, 290402.1535, 290413.3524, 290461.8015, 
    290462.2017, 290462.6616, 290463.1167, 290463.5671, 290464.0125, 
    290464.4528, 290464.8879, 290465.3175, 290465.7418, 290466.1604, 
    290466.5732, 290530.6604, 290531.4861, 290532.3232, 290533.1715, 
    290534.031, 290534.9012, 290535.7818, 290536.6725, 290537.5733, 
    290538.4837, 290539.4034, 290540.3323, 290541.2699, 290542.2161, 
    290543.1705, 290544.1328, 290545.103, 290546.0804, 290547.0647, 
    290548.056, 290549.0536, 290550.0573, 290551.0671, 290552.0823, 
    290553.1028, 290554.1281, 290554.3268, 290603.2123, 290604.2431, 
    290605.2782, 290606.3171, 290607.3596, 290608.4056, 290609.4544, 
    290610.5059, 290611.5597, 290612.6155, 290613.6731, 290614.7319, 
    290615.7919, 290616.8525, 290617.9135, 290618.9745, 290620.0354, 
    290621.0956, 290622.155, 290623.2131, 290624.2697, 290625.3245, 
    290626.377, 290627.4271, 290628.4743, 290629.5184, 290630.5589, 
    290631.5958, 290632.6285, 290633.6568, 290634.6803, 290635.699, 
    290636.7121, 290637.7196, 290638.7212, 290639.7165, 290640.7053, 
    290641.6872, 290642.6619, 290643.6291, 290644.5886, 290645.54, 
    290646.4831, 290647.0108, 290898.361, 290899.2903, 290900.2108, 
    290901.1218, 290902.0232, 290902.9147, 290903.796, 290904.6667, 
    290905.527, 290906.3761, 290907.214, 290908.0405, 290908.8552, 
    290909.658, 290910.4484, 290911.2264, 290911.9917, 290912.744, 
    290913.4832, 290914.2089, 290914.9211, 290915.6194, 290916.3038, 
    290916.9738, 290917.6293, 290918.2702, 290918.8962, 290919.5072, 
    290920.1029, 290920.6832, 290921.248, 290921.7969, 290922.33, 
    290922.8469, 290923.3476, 290923.832, 290924.2997, 290924.7508, 
    290925.1849, 290925.6023, 290926.0024, 290926.3854, 290926.7509, 
    290927.0992, 290927.4298, 290927.7428, 290928.038, 290928.3155, 
    290928.575, 290928.8164, 290929.0399, 290929.2452, 290929.4323, 
    290929.6012, 290929.7517, 290929.8838, 290929.9975, 290930.0929, 
    290930.1698, 290930.2282, 290930.2682, 290930.2896, 290930.2936, 
    290930.2936, 290947.0468, 290971.4515, 291043.4505, 291044.9703, 
    291046.6598, 291048.5069, 291050.4983, 291052.6199, 291054.8565, 
    291057.192, 291059.61, 291062.0928, 291064.6231, 291067.1825, 
    291069.7525, 292381.7522, 292381.4087, 292381.2759, 292351.1989, 
    292295.8257, 219517.0557, 220866.8662, 220920.498299999, 
    221851.3029, 222182.651699999, 222952.720100001, 224182.0206, 
    221185.8244, 221184.093599999, 221182.588, 221181.3101, 221180.2618, 
    221179.4449, 221178.8605, 221178.509400001, 221178.3924, 
    221178.3924, 221175.458000001, 221189.275599999, 221183.147700001, 
    221183.147700001, 221186.9114, 221186.9114, 221186.8237, 
    221186.5612, 221186.1272, 221185.526699999, 221184.8046, 
    221184.1326, 221183.678400001, 221183.448999999, 221183.447699999, 
    221183.6746, 221188.240900001, 221188.286900001, 221188.328500001, 
    221188.3654, 221188.3979, 221188.4256, 221188.448799999, 
    221188.450999999, 221193.5999, 221193.6721, 221193.7258, 
    221193.761, 221193.777799999, 221193.779300001, 221193.779300001, 
    221196.3542, 221196.354499999, 221197.991599999, 221197.1665, 
    221197.1665, 221199.986, 221201.3662, 221201.3662, 221201.0888, 
    221200.4087, 221204.7928, 221211.5538, 221216.300899999, 
    221217.516799999, 221228.089, 221228.089, 221230.3642, 221221.9608, 
    221214.1439, 221213.805199999, 221213.678400001, 221213.763699999, 
    221214.060699999, 221216.175100001, 221216.2849, 221216.3762, 
    221216.449200001, 221216.5035, 221216.5394, 221216.5568, 
    221216.558599999, 221216.558599999, 221222.791999999, 221222.819700001, 
    221222.801000001, 221222.736099999, 221222.7245, 221217.7325, 
    221231.698100001, 221242.064999999, 221239.1887, 221239.1887, 
    221239.198000001, 221244.2304, 221243.6538, 221243.6538, 
    221246.2478, 221246.2478, 221246.2432, 221246.2292, 221246.2061, 
    221246.173699999, 221246.131999999, 221246.0813, 221246.021199999, 
    221245.9519, 221245.916099999, 221236.0811, 221235.825999999, 
    221235.7499, 221235.853, 221236.1348, 221236.593800001, 221245.2271, 
    221245.674000001, 221245.9551, 221246.0689, 221246.0145, 
    221238.385500001, 221238.162900001, 221237.8849, 221237.5518, 
    221237.1634, 221236.720000001, 221236.2217, 221235.668400001, 
    221235.0605, 221234.3983, 221233.681700001, 221232.9112, 
    221232.0869, 221231.209100001, 221230.278000001, 221229.2938, 
    221228.256999999, 221227.1679, 221226.0266, 221224.833699999, 
    221223.589500001, 221222.294399999, 221220.9486, 221219.5527, 
    221218.1072, 221216.612299999, 221215.068600001, 221213.476600001, 
    221211.8368, 221210.149499999, 221208.4153, 221206.6349, 
    221204.808700001, 221202.937200001, 221201.021199999, 221199.061000001, 
    221197.0573, 221195.0107, 221192.9221, 221190.7917, 221188.6204, 
    221186.4087, 221184.157500001, 221181.8672, 221179.538799999, 
    221177.172900001, 221174.770199999, 221172.3313, 221169.8572, 
    221167.3484, 221164.8058, 221162.2303, 221159.622400001, 
    221156.983100001, 221154.313100001, 221151.613299999, 221148.884400001, 
    221146.1274, 221143.343, 221140.532099999, 221137.695599999, 
    221134.8342, 221131.948999999, 221129.0407, 221126.110300001, 
    221123.158600001, 221120.186699999, 221119.9911, 221114.6687, 
    221110.1796, 221105.662799999, 221101.1197, 221096.5516, 
    221091.959899999, 221087.346000001, 221082.7115, 221078.057499999, 
    221073.3857, 221068.6973, 221063.993799999, 221059.276699999, 
    221054.5474, 221049.8072, 221045.0579, 221040.3005, 221035.536800001, 
    221030.767999999, 221025.9958, 221021.2214, 221016.446599999, 
    221011.672499999, 221006.900599999, 221002.1325, 220997.3696, 
    220992.613399999, 220987.8652, 220983.126599999, 220978.399, 
    220973.683700001, 220968.9824, 220964.2963, 220959.627, 220954.9758, 
    220950.3442, 220945.7336, 220941.145199999, 220936.580800001, 
    220932.0414, 220927.5286, 220923.0437, 220918.588199999, 
    220914.163000001, 220909.770199999, 220905.410499999, 220901.0855, 
    220896.796499999, 220892.5448, 220889.698000001, 220800.500299999, 
    220798.131899999, 220795.6735, 220793.1434, 220790.560900001, 
    220787.945, 220785.315300001, 220782.6917, 220780.093699999, 
    220777.5407, 220713.7115, 220713.2818, 220712.7764, 220712.2739, 
    220711.774499999, 220711.2783, 220710.785499999, 220710.296, 
    220709.8103, 220709.328500001, 220708.850500001, 220708.376599999, 
    220707.907, 220707.4417, 220706.981000001, 220706.524900001, 
    220706.0737, 220705.6273, 220705.186000001, 220704.75, 220704.3193, 
    220703.893999999, 220703.474400001, 220703.0606, 220702.6524, 
    220702.250399999, 220701.8543, 220701.464600001, 220701.0812, 
    220700.7042, 220700.333900001, 220699.9702, 220699.613399999, 
    220699.2633, 220698.920299999, 220698.5845, 220698.255799999, 
    220697.9345, 220697.6206, 220697.314200001, 220697.0154, 
    220696.724400001, 220696.441099999, 220696.1657, 220695.8982, 
    220695.638699999, 220695.3873, 220695.144300001, 220694.909399999, 
    220694.682800001, 220694.4648, 220694.255100001, 220694.054, 
    220693.8616, 220649.488399999, 220648.8607, 220648.350400001, 
    220647.9595, 220640.237, 220640.1415, 220639.8928, 220639.671800001, 
    220639.4781, 220639.312100001, 220639.173699999, 220639.062999999, 
    220638.9801, 220638.924900001, 220638.897500001, 220638.8979, 
    220638.926000001, 220638.981899999, 220639.0656, 220639.176999999, 
    220639.316199999, 220639.482999999, 220639.677200001, 220639.8991, 
    220640.148399999, 220640.4252, 220640.7293, 220641.0606, 
    220641.419, 220641.804400001, 220642.216700001, 220642.6557, 
    220643.121400001, 220643.613700001, 220644.132200001, 220644.676899999, 
    220645.2476, 220645.8443, 220646.466499999, 220647.1143, 
    220647.7872, 220648.485300001, 220649.2081, 220649.955800001, 
    220650.727700001, 220651.5239, 220652.344000001, 220653.1877, 
    220654.0549, 220654.9454, 220655.8584, 220656.794399999, 
    220657.752499999, 220658.7327, 220659.7347, 220660.757999999, 
    220661.8025, 220662.867900001, 220663.953600001, 220665.0595, 
    220666.1853, 220667.330499999, 220668.4948, 220669.6778, 
    220670.8794, 220672.0989, 220673.336100001, 220674.590500001, 
    220675.8619, 220677.149800001, 220678.4538, 220679.773499999, 
    220681.1086, 220682.4585, 220683.823100001, 220685.2017, 
    220686.594000001, 220687.999600001, 220689.4179, 220690.8486, 
    220692.291300001, 220693.7455, 220695.2107, 220696.6866, 
    220698.172700001, 220699.668500001, 220701.173599999, 220819.9779, 
    220823.419500001, 220826.7785, 220830.0426, 220833.1998, 
    220836.2389, 220947.5481, 220949.3992, 220951.133199999, 
    220952.739800001, 220954.2093, 220955.5329, 220956.7029, 
    220973.3938, 220980.873600001, 221007.234200001, 221007.455800001, 
    221007.7205, 221007.993000001, 221008.273499999, 221008.561799999, 
    221008.857799999, 221009.1614, 221009.4726, 221009.791300001, 
    221010.1172, 221010.4505, 221063.115499999, 221063.782099999, 
    221064.434, 221065.0713, 221065.693600001, 221066.301100001, 
    221066.892999999, 221067.469599999, 221068.0305, 221068.5756, 
    221069.104699999, 221069.617699999, 221070.114499999, 221070.594699999, 
    221071.058499999, 221071.5054, 221071.9355, 221072.3486, 
    221072.7446, 221073.123400001, 221073.4848, 221073.8287, 
    221074.154999999, 221074.4637, 221074.7546, 221075.0276, 
    221075.078400001, 221087.465700001, 221087.7173, 221087.9509, 
    221088.1665, 221088.3639, 221088.543, 221088.7039, 221088.8463, 
    221088.9705, 221089.076300001, 221089.1635, 221089.2324, 
    221089.2827, 221089.3145, 221089.3278, 221089.3226, 221089.299000001, 
    221089.2568, 221089.196, 221089.116800001, 221089.019099999, 
    221088.903000001, 221088.7685, 221088.615700001, 221088.444599999, 
    221088.2552, 221088.047599999, 221087.821900001, 221087.5781, 
    221087.316500001, 221087.036800001, 221086.7393, 221086.4242, 
    221086.0912, 221085.740800001, 221085.373, 221084.988, 221084.5857, 
    221084.166300001, 221083.73, 221083.276799999, 221082.807, 
    221082.320599999, 221082.0393, 220946.449999999, 220945.938100001, 
    220945.41, 220944.865900001, 220944.3061, 220943.730599999, 
    220943.139599999, 220942.533399999, 220941.912, 220941.275800001, 
    220940.624700001, 220939.9592, 220939.2794, 220938.5855, 
    220937.877499999, 220937.1559, 220936.4209, 220935.672599999, 
    220934.9113, 220934.1373, 220933.3507, 220932.5517, 220931.740800001, 
    220930.9179, 220930.0836, 220929.2379, 220928.381100001, 
    220927.513499999, 220926.635500001, 220925.747199999, 220924.8488, 
    220923.9407, 220923.0233, 220922.0965, 220921.1611, 220920.2169, 
    220919.2644, 220918.304, 220917.3358, 220916.360200001, 220915.377499999, 
    220914.3879, 220913.391799999, 220912.3894, 220911.381100001, 
    220910.3673, 220909.347999999, 220908.323799999, 220907.295, 
    220906.261700001, 220905.224400001, 220904.1833, 220903.138900001, 
    220902.0913, 220901.040999999, 220899.988, 220898.933, 220897.8763, 
    220896.818, 220895.7585, 220894.698100001, 220893.6373, 220892.9416, 
    220805.090500001, 220652.0131, 220578.619200001, 220471.1764, 
    220469.103599999, 220467.1666, 220465.3793, 220463.7544, 
    220462.303400001, 220461.036900001, 220459.964, 220459.0921, 
    220458.4276, 220457.975199999, 220457.7381, 220457.7182, 
    220503.026799999, 220499.1679, 220497.3116, 220076.619999999, 
    219517.0557, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), dim = c(567L, 3L))), class = c("XYZ", "POLYGON", "sfg"
    ))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(input = "NAD83(NSRS2007) / Florida East + NAVD88 height", 
        wkt = "COMPOUNDCRS[\"NAD83(NSRS2007) / Florida East + NAVD88 height\",\n    PROJCRS[\"NAD83(NSRS2007) / Florida East\",\n        BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83(NSRS2007)\",\n            DATUM[\"NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2007)\",\n                ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                    LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",6759]],\n            PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]]],\n        CONVERSION[\"unnamed\",\n            METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n            PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",24.3333333333333,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n            PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",-81,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n            PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.999941176470588,\n                SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n            PARAMETER[\"False easting\",200000,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n            PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n        CS[Cartesian,2],\n            AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n                ORDER[1],\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,\n                    ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]],\n            AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n                ORDER[2],\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,\n                    ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]]],\n    VERTCRS[\"NAVD88 height\",\n        VDATUM[\"North American Vertical Datum 1988\"],\n        CS[vertical,1],\n            AXIS[\"gravity-related height (H)\",up,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,\n                    ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]]]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 270202.1163, 
    ymin = 219517.0557, xmax = 292381.7522, ymax = 224182.0206
    ), class = "bbox"), z_range = structure(c(zmin = 0, zmax = 0
    ), class = "z_range"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(Shape_Leng = NA_integer_, 
Shape_Area = NA_integer_), class = "factor", levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do with this area ultimately? Put it in a large las file for later use? Produce a DTM/CHM/whatever for this region of interest?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, yes, put in a larger `LAS` file for later use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `clip_roi()` the default consists in loading the data in R as you noticed. However this function is also optimized to do not load anything at all in R if you put the output into a file. Each point will be read from the input las files and streamed to the output file.

```r
opt_output_files(LAS_List) <- "/path/to/folder/region_of_interest"
opt_laz_compression(LAS_list) = TRUE # If you want region_of_interest.laz
roi_ctg = clip_roi(LAS_List, sf_object)
```

This will create `region_of_interest.laz` but is likely to take a long time with such a big and complex polygon. Also this will likely create a very large file. I'd rather try with a smaller polygon the first time.